# Kotlin coroutine - multiple error cause crash before reach the catch block

Tags: android, kotlin, error-handling, try-catch, coroutine

I have a problem: when my code throw multiple exception in coroutine fn (in background service) then the main app crash before execute catch block in background service, but after that execute the catch block. **How can I fixed that?** 
The code works fine if throw 1 error, but crash if throws multiple error.

Expectation: catch first error and stop execution in runBlocking without crash the main app.

Error message:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-8
    Process: ..., PID: 9260
    RuntimeException: my error
        at MyBackgroundService ...
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:234)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:594)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.access$runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:60)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:742)
```

The following code is very simplified version of my code which represented how looks my structured concurrency:

```
class MyBackgroundService : IntentService("..."), CoroutineScope {

    private var cJob: Job = Job()

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.IO + cJob

    override fun onHandleIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        /*...*/
        try {
            runBlocking {
                fn1();
                fn2();
            }
        } catch(e: RuntimeException) {
            //before execution reach this the main app crashed with my custom error
            //after that the app execute the catch block code and other coroutine fn still running in fn2
        }
    }

    private suspend fun fn1() {
        withContext(coroutineContext) {
             /*...*/
        }
    }

    private suspend fun fn2() {
        withContext(coroutineContext) {
             /*...*/
             fn3()
             /*other similar fn calls*/
             /*after throw exception in fn3 the other coroutine functions still running */
        }
    }

    private suspend fun fn3() {
        launch {
            fn4() 
        }
    }

    private suspend fun fn4() {
        coroutineScope {
            launch {
               /*...*/
               fn5()
            }
        }
    }

    fun CoroutineScope.fn5() {
        for (/*...*/) {
             launch {
                 fn6()
             }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun fn6() {
        coroutineScope {
            launch {
               /*...*/
               if (/*..*/) {
                   throw RuntimeException("my error") //this called multiple time because of for
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try SupervisorJob instead of job

Comment: @FahadAlotaibi I think your mention idea is bad, because as I know: in the case of  SupervisorJob the failure or cancellation of a child does not cause the supervisor job to fail and does not affect its other children. But I want to stop other children and parent when the exceptions occurred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem:
ambiguous coroutinecontext is in fn3, so the fix:

```
private suspend fun fn3() {
    coroutineScope {
        launch {
            fn4() 
        }
    }
}
```